# Несколько одновременных запросов через Retrofit2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Новичок в андроид и немного не понятно как сделать несколько вызовов.
В активити например есть кнопка по клику на нее вызывается метод

```
private void getWorkDetail(String idOrg, String orgTicketCode) {
    AmurApi amurApi = new HttpService().call();
    final Call<WorkModel> work = amurApi.getWorkDetail(idOrg, orgTicketCode);

    work.enqueue(new Callback<WorkModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<WorkModel> call, Response<WorkModel> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(Config.TAG_DEBUG, "Данные по работе получены");
                setData(response.body());
            } else {
                Log.d(Config.TAG_DEBUG, "WorkActivity response code " + response.code());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<WorkModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(Config.TAG_DEBUG, "WorkActivity failure " + t);
        }
    });
}
```

Данные получаю все нормально, но мне нужно вызвать еще два методы для получения данных getJobDetail, getWorkComments.

Подскажите как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Решил следующим образом (возможно не совсем верно и есть другой вариант)

```
 AmurApi amurApi = new HttpService().call();

 final Call<WorkModel> work = amurApi.getWorkDetail(idOrg, orgTicketCode);
 work.enqueue(getWorkCallback());

 final Call<JobModel> job = amurApi.getJob(jobCode);
 job.enqueue(getJobCallback());

 private Callback<WorkModel> getWorkCallback() {
    return new Callback<WorkModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<WorkModel> call, Response<WorkModel> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(Config.TAG_DEBUG, "Данные по работе получены");
                WorkModel data = response.body();
                TextView orgTicketCodeView = findViewById(R.id.orgTicketCodeView);
                orgTicketCodeView.setText(data.getOrgTicketCode());
                TextView cstWorkNameView = findViewById(R.id.typeWorkView);
                cstWorkNameView.setText(data.getCstWorkName());
                TextView orgStatusCodeTextView = findViewById(R.id.orgStatusCodeTextView);
                orgStatusCodeTextView.setText(data.getOrgStatusCodeText());
            } else {
                Log.d(Config.TAG_DEBUG, "WorkActivity response code " + response.code());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<WorkModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(Config.TAG_DEBUG, "WorkActivity failure " + t);
        }
    };
}

private Callback<JobModel> getJobCallback() {
    return new Callback<JobModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JobModel> call, Response<JobModel> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(Config.TAG_DEBUG, "Данные по заданию получены");
                JobModel data = response.body();
                TextView inScheduleView = findViewById(R.id.inScheduleView);
                inScheduleView.setText(data.getDateC());
            } else {
                Log.d(Config.TAG_DEBUG, "WorkActivity response code " + response.code());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JobModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(Config.TAG_DEBUG, "WorkActivity failure " + t);
        }
    };
}
```